# List of entries in iOS development

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I'm pretty new to iOS programming and I'm looking for a way to do something. I Want a single view with a list of entries. On top of the page, there is a + sign to add a new entry. An entry is just a text that you've entered (so of course you can click open the text on the list, and swipe to left to delete it).

What's the object that I need to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a job for [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: @Jente http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/ (google for "uitableview example").